# importing python logging module settings

Tags: python, logging, module

I've got a python server that was using logging module. So far it was just:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='server.log',level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
```

Now I want to add few handlers to the logger. This is about 15 lines of code. I don't want to put it into the main server.py file to make it hold the most important server stuff. The question is - what is the suggested way to do this in python.

I have moved my logging handlers definitions into another module and have imported it:

```
import logdefs
```

but then this import is never used (I never use `logdefs.something`). Is that ok? Another question is - how does it work that logging module is loaded from a server.py's submodule and all the logging settings are available for the rest of its application (modifications are global instead of local)? Is all logging module content available as some kind of a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `logging.basicConfig`, you could call

```
logging.config.fileConfig(config_file)
```

and place the [configuration in a file.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html)

---

For you second question, if you look at the [`logging/__init__.py` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dbad4564cd12/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1640), you'll see

```
root = RootLogger(WARNING)
Logger.root = root
Logger.manager = Manager(Logger.root)
```

This code gets called when `logging` is first imported.
So when a submodule modifies or access the root logger, it is affecting or accessing the same root logger as the module that first imported `logging`.